# Как в C# обходились, когда не было Dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, из вне приходит какой-то объект неизвестного типа.

Известно, что объекты могут быть разными(разные поля), но одно поле всегда есть у данного объекта.

Через Dynamic- это тривиальная задача, а как это делалось, когда он не был введен в C#?

**UPD**

Пример кода работы с Dapper, где руками мапятся колонки

```
var codes = conn.Query<dynamic>(...sql and params here...)
                 .Select<dynamic,Code>(s=>new Code{Id = s.Id, Type = s.Type, Value = s.code, Description = s.Description});
```

Comment: совпадающие вещи это ж общий интерфейс.

Comment: рефлексия например

Comment: @Grundy, а можно примерчик?

Comment: @iluxa1810, сначала нужен пример с dynamic, чтобы было понятно с какой из частей возникает проблема

Comment: @Grundy, добавил.

Comment: @iluxa1810, что-то в этом примере проще конкретный тип подставить вместо dynamic

Comment: @Grunby,Dapper мапит только тогда, когда названия колонок совпадают с полями класса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44989/discussion-between-grundy-and-iluxa1810).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если говорить в целом, то до появления dynamic работа с логикой объектов неизвестного типа (а знание о том, что у объекта есть определенный атрибут и, тем более, операции с ним - это, хочешь не хочешь, а работа с логикой) в языке программирования со строгой типизацией считалось дурным тоном и bad practice. Некоторые олдфаги, типа меня, считают так до сих пор.

Но если очень надо, то есть два варианта: наследование и Reflection.

Наследование применяется в тех случаях, когда у вас есть контроль над моделью данных - тогда можно сделать либо базовый класс, либо (еще лучше) интерфейс с нужным полем, отнаследоваться, в нужном месте скастовать и далее работать уже как с обычным объектом.

Вариант с reflection применяется, если наследование делать нельзя или не хочется - например, мы используем модель данных из внешней библиотеки. В этом случае, мы просто лезем внутрь объекта и при помощи reflection'а выдираем нужное поле.

Оформить этот процесс в реализацию можно множеством способов. Можно использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк, который обернет несколько команд в одну типа GetPropertyValue. Можно сделать класс с нужными полями и, используя автомаппер (которых есть великое множество), скопировать поля неизвестного объекта в наш объект. Можно все поля неизвестного объекта скинуть в Dictionary и работать уже с ним.