# Когда и зачем применяется динамический тип

Tags: c#

Зачем используют тип dynamic и как понять, когда его использовать. Тем более что в теории написано, что  правильно ли мы все сделали с этим типом, будет видно только в рантайме. Вижу простые примеры, которые ничего не показывают именно зачем он и когда его надо применять.
Вот пример теста от Luxoft. Зачем ту. динамический тип.

```
 class Person
    {
        private int age = 89;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var person=new Person();

            try
            {
                dynamic dynamicPerson = person;
                Console.WriteLine($"dynamic {dynamicPerson.age}");
             }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("dynamic bloc");

            }

            try
            {
                int theage = (int) (person.GetType().GetField("age", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(person));
                Console.WriteLine($"reflection: {theage}");
            }
            catch 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("reflection in bloc");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

На  выходе получается

```
dynamic bloc
reflection 89
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем тут тип dynamic?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649846/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d1%83%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-dynamic)

Comment: @Grundy разве дубликат? Там ответ только про foreach, но не про применение dynamic в общем

Comment: _Зачем ту. динамический тип_ - попробуй его убрать :)

Comment: а с чего бы вдруг вы вот так просто `dynamicPerson.age` получили бы доступ к приватному полю?

Comment: @tym32167 ну тут более  менее ясно, что приватовское поле, динамик зачем я не знаю , хочется понять смысл динамика вообще

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, ну так в том и смысл, что тебе _вывелось_ в момент выполнения, а не упало при компиляции.

Comment: @tym32167, да, мне показалось что написано: зачем тип dynamic? А там немного не то

Comment: @Grundy какой смысл в отложенности подобной?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, просто огромнейший!

Comment: @tym32167, вот этот наверное получше: [Как в C# обходились, когда не было Dynamic?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563350/186999)

Comment: @Grundy )) Ваш ответ прекрасен, просто я хочу постичь эту прелесть динамического типа

Comment: @Grundy хз, я бы ожидал ответ в стиле "вот в этих конкретных случаях используйте dynamic, так как иначе будет больно тут и тут". Но у меня таких вопросов нет, писать ответ нет времени, потому хз это ли ждет автор или нет.

Comment: @tym32167 Именно этих ответов , и жду ,хочется наглядности

Comment: Ну, пару примеров есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690837/312041) и в ответах рядышком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим нам нужно реализовать класс, который возвращает какой-то объект, который представляет из себя строчку результируюзего запроса к БД.

Нам заранее никак не известно, какой запрос отправит пользователь в БД, что бы определить поля класса, мы не знаем какие типы на вернет SQL.

Что мы можем сделать?

- Мы можем сделать класс, который внутри себя держит массив `Object` и метод или индексатор, который по названию возвращает тот или иной `Object`. Однако, это немного не естественно.
- Можем воспользоваться dynamic

Именно в этом случае нам пригодится механизм, который может работать с заранее неизвестным на этапе компиляции объектом -`dynamic`

Он позволяет в естественной манере(через оператор "точка") общаться с неизвестными на этапе компиляции членами типа(полями, методами и т п...), как будто они есть.

Без него, нам бы пришлось в явном виде пользоваться рефлексией(`dynamic` прячет ее внутри себя).

Именно по этому пути пошел `Dapper`, который может вернуть dynamic, а пользователь его может разобрать под себя.

Более того, если мы унаследуемся от `DynamicObject` и переопределим методы, то сможем создать свою оболочку с блэекджеком и всем остальным.

В самом простом случае этот объект-это просто словарь , который возвращает те или иные данные по имени свойства, а в более сложной реализации там может быть что угодно.

За все приходится платить=>есть конечно и минусы:

1. Пониженная скорость работы из-за рефлексии
2. Отсутствие `IntelliSense`
3. Компилятор не подсветит красным цветом метод в которым вы допустили ошибку.

Как следствие, если такое возможно, то его нужно избегать и использовать только, когда в нем есть необходимость.

Comment: Зря вы сводите dynamic к словарям: со словарями удобнее работать как со словарями. Если бы dynamic был только про словари, это был бы очень странный dynamic...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поправил формулировку.